# Laravel - Upload PDF from string

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Quickbooks PHP SDK to generate a PDF from an Invoice but I would like to upload the PDF to the server. Currently I can request the Invoice and download the PDF but how do I tell Laravel to take the PDF and upload it without it being downloaded?

```
$invoice = $dataService->FindById("Invoice", "130147");
$pdfContent = $dataService->DownloadPDF($invoice, null, true);          
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"');
echo $pdfContent;
exit();
```

Instead of it downloading I would like to do something like:

```
$path = $pdfContent->storeAs('public/pdf', invoice.pdf);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution outside of my question above.

The Quickbooks API allows the ability to pass a file location in the second variable. Also the 3rd variable can be set to true to generate a raw PDF.

```
$invoice = $dataService->FindById("Estimate", "130147");
$data = $dataService->DownloadPDF($invoice, base_path('/pdf/'), false);
```

While this is a great simple solution I wonder if there is an solution with how I was originally going about?